# React Native Props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am new to React Native. I am making a music app and I'm using the react-native-track-player module which works. But now, I'm trying to pass `songlist` as props from my `Flatlist` to the player component.

So first, I am able to show the moods. Then when I pass props/move to `Songlist` screen I am be able to show the songlist and it will display the title and artist in a `Flatlist`. So when I click on one of them, It will go to the `Play` screen. I want to be able to pass the props and play the song. But the song will not be played and crash. I am not sure whether I am passing the props properly. I will really appreciate if anyone can help me with this issue.

This is my `Cluster1` screen (first screen)

```
export default class Cluster1 extends Component{
 render(){
  return(
      <View style={styles.container}>
          <SectionList          
           renderItem={({item,index})=>{
               return(
              <SectionListItem  item={item} index={index}> </SectionListItem>);}} 
                  renderSectionHeader={({ section }) => {
                      return (<SectionHeader section={section} />);}}
                        sections={ClusterData}
                        keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.name}>
          </SectionList>
      </View>      
  );
}}
class SectionHeader extends Component {
  render() {
      return (
          <View style={styles.header}>  
              <Text style={styles.headertext}>
              {this.props.section.title}       
              </Text>
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={ () => Actions.SongList({ section: this.props.section}) }>
                <Text style ={styles.Play}> Play
                </Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
      );
  }}

class SectionListItem extends Component{
  render(){
      return(
          <View>
          <Text style={styles.moodname}>{this.props.item.name}</Text>
          </View>
      );
  }
}
```

This is my `SongList` screen (second screen)

```
export default class App extends Component {
render() {
return (
    <View>
    <FlatList

    data={this.props.section.songlist}
    renderItem={({item,index,rowId})=>{
        return(
            <FlatListItem  item={item} index={index}>
            </FlatListItem>);}}>
    </FlatList>
    </View>
);}}
class FlatListItem extends Component{
 render(){
    return(
        <View>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={ () => Actions.Play({songIndex: 0, songlist: this.props.item.songlist, item: this.props.item}) }>
        <Text style={styles.itemTitle}>{this.props.item.songtitle}</Text>
        <Text style={styles.itemArtist}>{this.props.item.artist}</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
    );}}
```

So when I click on the songtitle/artist, the app will stop. I think the error could be `await TrackPlayer.add(this.props.item.songlist);` but I am not sure.

This is my `Play` screen

```
import TrackPlayer from 'react-native-track-player';

export default class Play extends Component{
componentDidMount()
{
    TrackPlayer.setupPlayer().then(async () => {  
        // Adds a track to the queue
        await TrackPlayer.add(this.props.item.songlist);
        // Starts playing it
        TrackPlayer.play();  
    });
}
  onPressPlay = () => {
      TrackPlayer.play();
  };
onPressPause = () => {
      TrackPlayer.pause();
  };
render() {
return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style= {{flexDirection :'column'}}>
      <TouchableOpacity style= {styles.play} onPress = {this.onPressPlay}>
          <Text style = {{fontWeight:'bold',textAlign:'center',color:'white'}}>Play</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <TouchableOpacity style= {styles.pause} onPress = {this.onPressPause}>
          <Text style = {{fontWeight:'bold',textAlign:'center',color:'white'}}>Pause</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>        
        </View>
      </View>
  );}}
```

This is my where I get my `data` in another file

```
const ClusterData = [
{ title: 'Cluster1', 
data: 
[
  {name: 'passionate'},
  {name: 'rousing'},
  {name: 'confident'},
  {name: 'boisterous'},
  {name: 'rowdy'}
],
 songlist:
[
  {
    id: '2222',
    url: 'http://tegos.kz/new/mp3_full/Post_Malone_-_Better_Now.mp3',
    title: 'Better Now',
    artist: 'Post Malone',
  },
  {
    id: '2',
    url: 'http://tegos.kz/new/mp3_full/5_Seconds_Of_Summer_-_Youngblood.mp3',
    title: 'YoungBlood',
    artist: '5SOS',
  },
]
},
{ title: 'Cluster2', 
  data: 
[
  {name: 'rollicking'},
  {name: 'cheerful'},
  {name: 'fun'},
  {name: 'sweet'},
  {name: 'amiable'},
  {name: 'natured'}
],
  songlist:
  [
    {
      id: '1111',
      url: 'http://tegos.kz/new/mp3_full/Yellow_Claw_and_San_Holo_-_Summertime.mp3',
      title: 'Summertime',
      artist: 'Yellow Claw',
    },
    {
      id: '1',
      url: 'http://tegos.kz/new/mp3_full/Luis_Fonsi_feat._Daddy_Yankee_-_Despacito.mp3',
      title: 'Despacito',
      artist: 'Luis Fonsi',
    },
  ]
},
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to log the this.props.item.songlist inside componentDidMount Play Component? And.. What Actions.Play does? What is Actions?

Comment: Actions.Play is from react-native-router-flux. It will go to the Play file/screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing wrong props in **FlatListItem**, now there is no songlist object beacause **item** itself is a songlist item, 
So just pass it like this `Actions.Play({songIndex: 0, item: this.props.item}) }>` and  Update inside **Play** class by replacing `this.props.item.songlist` to `this.props.item`

Below is the complete working example

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  View,
  Text,
  FlatList,
  TouchableOpacity,
  SectionList,
} from 'react-native';

import TrackPlayer from 'react-native-track-player';

const ClusterData = [
  {
    title: 'Cluster1',
    data: [
      { name: 'passionate' },
      { name: 'rousing' },
      { name: 'confident' },
      { name: 'boisterous' },
      { name: 'rowdy' },
    ],
    songlist: [
      {
        id: '2222',
        url: 'http://tegos.kz/new/mp3_full/Post_Malone_-_Better_Now.mp3',
        title: 'Better Now',
        artist: 'Post Malone',
      },
      {
        id: '2',
        url:
          'http://tegos.kz/new/mp3_full/5_Seconds_Of_Summer_-_Youngblood.mp3',
        title: 'YoungBlood',
        artist: '5SOS',
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    title: 'Cluster2',
    data: [
      { name: 'rollicking' },
      { name: 'cheerful' },
      { name: 'fun' },
      { name: 'sweet' },
      { name: 'amiable' },
      { name: 'natured' },
    ],
    songlist: [
      {
        id: '1111',
        url:
          'http://tegos.kz/new/mp3_full/Yellow_Claw_and_San_Holo_-_Summertime.mp3',
        title: 'Summertime',
        artist: 'Yellow Claw',
      },
      {
        id: '1',
        url:
          'http://tegos.kz/new/mp3_full/Luis_Fonsi_feat._Daddy_Yankee_-_Despacito.mp3',
        title: 'Despacito',
        artist: 'Luis Fonsi',
      },
    ],
  },
];

export class MusicPlayer extends Component {
  state = {
    showSongList: false,
    activeSection: null,
  };

  updateState = item => {
    this.setState(item);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, paddingTop: 20 }}>
        {this.state.showSongList ? (
          <SongList section={this.state.activeSection} />
        ) : (
          <SectionList
            renderItem={({ item, index }) => {
              return <SectionListItem item={item} index={index} />;
            }}
            renderSectionHeader={({ section }) => {
              return (
                <SectionHeader
                  section={section}
                  updateState={this.updateState}
                />
              );
            }}
            sections={ClusterData}
            keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.name}
          />
        )}
      </View>
    );
  }
}
class SectionHeader extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ margin: 20, marginBottom: 10 }}>
        <Text style={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }}>{this.props.section.title}</Text>
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() =>
            this.props.updateState({
              showSongList: true,
              activeSection: this.props.section,
            })
          }
        >
          <Text style={{ color: 'blue' }}> Play</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

class SectionListItem extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text style={{ margin: 5, marginLeft: 20, fontStyle: 'italic' }}>
          {this.props.item.name}
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
export class SongList extends Component {
  state = {
    isPlayActive: false,
  };

  startPlay = data => {
    this.setState({
      isPlayActive: true,
      data: data,
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <FlatList
          data={this.props.section.songlist}
          renderItem={({ item, index, rowId }) => {
            return (
              <FlatListItem
                item={item}
                index={index}
                startPlay={this.startPlay}
              />
            );
          }}
        />
        {this.state.isPlayActive && <Play {...this.state.data} />}
      </View>
    );
  }
}
class FlatListItem extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ backgroundColor: '#555', height: 80, marginTop: 20 }}>
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() =>
            this.props.startPlay({
              songIndex: 0,
              item: this.props.item,
            })
          }
        >
          <Text
            style={{
              paddingTop: 10,
              textAlign: 'center',
              fontSize: 20,
              color: '#FFF',
            }}
          >
            {this.props.item.title}
          </Text>
          <Text
            style={{
              textAlign: 'center',
              fontSize: 15,
              paddingTop: 10,
              color: '#FFF',
            }}
          >
            {this.props.item.artist}
          </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export class Play extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    TrackPlayer.setupPlayer().then(async () => {
      // Adds a track to the queue
      await TrackPlayer.add(this.props.item);
      // Starts playing it
      TrackPlayer.play();
    });
  }
  onPressPlay = () => {
    TrackPlayer.play();
  };
  onPressPause = () => {
    TrackPlayer.pause();
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ height: 400 }}>
        <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
          <TouchableOpacity
            style={{
              backgroundColor: '#f0f0f0',
              height: 40,
              flex: 1,
              alignItems: 'center',
              justifyContent: 'center',
              marginRight: 10,
            }}
            onPress={this.onPressPlay}
          >
            <Text
              style={{
                fontWeight: 'bold',
                textAlign: 'center',
                color: 'black',
              }}
            >
              Play
            </Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <TouchableOpacity
            style={{
              flex: 1,
              backgroundColor: '#f0f0f0',
              height: 40,
              alignItems: 'center',
              justifyContent: 'center',
            }}
            onPress={this.onPressPause}
          >
            <Text
              style={{
                fontWeight: 'bold',
                textAlign: 'center',
                color: 'black',
              }}
            >
              Pause
            </Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I followed your code but I am not sure why when I click on the flatlist I would get 'Unfortunately, myProject has stopped.

Comment: I posted the screenshot of it

Comment: @OhsnapItskhai can you also share the error message printed in android studio's logcat,

Comment: Your method seemed to be working. It works when I wrote data={ClusterData}. But 
 when I am passing props from the Cluster1 screen(just edited), and write data={this.props.section.songlist} instead, It would crash when I click on the list. Basically from `Cluster1` screen to `Songlist` screen and then when I click on the flatlist of the song the app will crash which is shown on the screenshot. Thanks for your help I really appreciate it.

Comment: @OhsnapItskhai That's great. Please do upvote and accept my answer if it was helpful. Thanks.

Comment: but why does it crash when I put it like data={this.props.section.songlist}?

Comment: @OhsnapItskhai, 

First of all, In your Cluster1 Class, you are passing sections prop not section prop. You are missing 's' at the last.  Change sections to section.

Second, your  ClusterData is an array, and you are directly passing it to each SectionList item. So you can  songlist  only using index  for example this.props.section[0].songlist
or else pass props from SectionList like sections={ClusterData[index]} then you can access with this.props.section.songlist

Comment: I think you were misunderstood. I pass props from Cluster1 class to Songlist class. Which works fine. How do I pass from Songlist class to Play class. I am not passing props from Cluster1 class to Play class. In my play class I changed it to await TrackPlayer.add(this.props.item.songlist[index]); but I got rejection id. I'll post the screenshot of it

Comment: @OhsnapItskhai I have updated my answer with a complete example with explanation. Please try the example.. Hope it will help.

Comment: Everything is smooth but why it doesn't change song when at first I click on the first one then when I clicked on the second one, it still continue playing the first one

Comment: I can't change song unless I restart the application